# How to use angular 2 in exsisting nodejs application only in specific pages

Tags: angular

*emphasized text*I have a large web application which is already developed using Nodejs. 
I am adding features to the application using angular 2 and use them inside the exisisting ejs pages with the `<selector-name>`

One such example is **`<project-details>`**.
When I load pages which has angular2 coponents, I dont get any errors, but the rest of the application throws error in the console but works fine as early.

The error which I get in the console looks like
[image]

The selector "project-details" did not match any elements

What is the best practice include angular2 modules only in required pages and get rid of getting this error from other pages?

I use angular2 latest version with webpack.

**Update1:** 
All components are rendered correctly and work fine on the page I need to include them. 
I just want to get rid of this error on the pages where I don't need angular components ie: pages without `<project-details></project-details>`

```
module.exports= {
    entry : "./main.ts",
    output : {
        path:__dirname,
        filename : "./dist/bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions : ['.js','.ts']
    },
    module: {
        loaders : [{
            test : /\.ts/, 
            loaders: ['ts-loader'], 
            exclude :/node_modules/
        }]
    }
}
```

main.ts:

```
import "core-js";
import "reflect-metadata";
import "zone.js/dist/zone"

import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ProjectModule } from './project/project.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(ProjectModule);
```

project.module.ts:

```
// core 
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule }  from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { ProjectComponent } from './project.component';
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule, 
    BrowserModule, 
    HttpModule, 
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    ProjectComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ 
    ProjectComponent 
  ],
  providers : [
    ProjectService
  ]
})

export class ProjectModule { }
```

project.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from './project.model';
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'project-details',
  templateUrl: '/app/project.component.html'
})
export class ProjectComponent {

  constructor(private  projectService: ProjectService){

  }
}
```

footer.ejs:

```
<script src="/app/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

**NOTE:** This setup is already working fine without any issues. 
I just want to get rid of this error on the pages where I don't need angular components ie: pages without `<project-details></project-details>` and having some other angular2 component.

Comment: Please share Minimum working example that we can look into

Comment: included the code

Comment: where are you declaring this component? It seems that you are not declaring it correctly in one of the modules of your application. Do you have more than one module?

Comment: I declared it correctly and working fine. How to get rid of "The selector "project-details" did not match any elements" from **the pages where I don't actually need angular component**.

Comment: what about `ProjectComponent_Host` ? Is the HTML shared between different Components?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error means that there is no component with selector **project-details**.

Possible Reasons.

1. No Component exists with that selector.
2. There might be a typo.
3. The component might not be a part of that module.
4. Component might not be in the declaration in the module.

More information needed to give exact fix.

Update:
As fixed in team viewer, I am updating the post.

1. Include the scripts **bundle.js** in those pages which uses angular2
   components not in all pages as in the footer.
2. Add Custom_Elements_Schema in your module as below

   ```
   import{ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core'
   @NgModule({
         declarations: [ ... ],
         exports: [ ... ],
         imports: [ ... ],
         schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
   })
   ```

Comment: **EDIT:** 
All components are rendered correctly and work fine on the page I need to include them. 
I just want to get rid of this error on the pages where I don't need angular components ie: pages without <project-details></project-details>

Comment: Thanks and i found some relevant helpful answers from your answers list.

Comment: @sith please do mention in those respective posts. Happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

With angular2, all the components (including pages and custom tags) and filters (pipes)  are defined in the app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProjectDetails,
   SomeFilter,SomeComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpModule, Core],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

If you have a component `project-details` that will be part of a page, then its ts class has to be added to the `@NgModule` `declarations`.

Regarding the `project-details` ts file itself `project-details.component.ts`, it has to define the selector as annotation

for example

```
@Component({

  selector: 'project-details',
  templateUrl: 'project-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['project-details.component.css'],
})
export class PRojectDetails {
...
}
```

Comment: I have exact this setup. **EDIT:** 
All components are rendered correctly and work fine on the page I need to include them. 
I just want to get rid of this error on the pages where I don't need angular components ie: pages without <project-details></project-details> tag